# super() method not giving error when no parent class is defined

Tags: java, super

```
class child
{
    child()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        child obj=new child();
    }
}
```

In this code when I a create an object of class child , the child constructor is called. But why is it not giving error as there is no parent class. What does the super() do here?
Whose constructor is the super() keyword calling?

Comment: It is worth noting that the explicit `super()` in child would have been silently inserted if you had omitted it. And, you are implicitly extending `java.lang.Object` (e.g. you can Override `equals()` and `toString()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is calling the constructor of the `Object class` as all object in java extends by default to the Object class.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

```
Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. 
All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.
```

Answer (score 6):

In Java every object implicitly extends `Object`. Calling super here will just call Object's constructor. On another note you should really abide by naming conventions such as capitalizing class names.

Answer (score 3):

You're invoking the `Object` method, from which all other classes descend eventually.

First up, clarifying the class hierarchy in this situation, [the inheritance section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) in the Java tutorial states:

> Excepting `Object`, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). **In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of `Object`.**

Then, for the [tutorial stuff on using `super`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass.
>
> If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. **Object does have such a constructor**, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `Object` class, in the `java.lang package`, sits at the top of the class hierarchy tree. Every class is a descendant, direct or indirect, of the Object class.

All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class. Thats why `super()` in your case is actually calling the constructor of `Object` class.

Answer (score 1):

Every class we create in Java is an implicit descendant of "Object" object (in other words, subclass of Object).  Hence when ever you are making a call to super() it implicitly calls the constructor of Object class. The basic reason to have this feature is to generalize the common features like:

```
    synchnronizaton - like wati()
    object identity - like hashcode(), equals()
```

and many more.

Thanks,
JK